# Path in the server to store images

Tags: android, server

I'm designing a DB. in the DB, there is a field that stores the link to images.

Where in the server should these images be added? Should it be in public_html? These images will be used in the Android app.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the images are saved in a specific directory for them. For example:

```
.../images_stored/
```

Although it is for android pictures, I imagine that also can be accessed from ios or another OS, for example instagram images are for any (Android / iOS / Web) operating system.